# KeyDown event and AltGr

Tags: wpf, keydown

> How can I detect Alt Gr key press?

I have `KeyDown` event attached to a WPF window.

When I press <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> then the `Key` parameter in the `KeyEventArg` object equals `LeftCtrl`.

Also when I check `Keyboard.IsKeyDown` and `Keyboard.Modifiers` it always returns `Control` key pressed.

How can I detect `AltGr` key press? What's the best method to do it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How can i detect `AltGr` key press?

Comment: **Alt Gr** is simply **Alt + Ctrl** and can't be detected via `KeyDown` as a single key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution for my problem. `AltGr` was handled by `Menu` component.

I change my `KeyDown` event to `KeyUp` so now i catching `AltGr` properly.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this post answers your question:

[How to distinguish between multiple key combination in wpf/c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26137556/how-to-distinguish-between-multiple-key-combination-in-wpf-c)

Specifically this section of code is how you see the AltGr key press:

```
private void WindowKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    var alt = e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Alt);
    var ctrl = e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Control);
    var altGr = alt & ctrl;
    var shift = e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Shift);
}
```

This is because Alt GR is registered as "ALT + LEFT CTRL" by windows

Comment: I know that Alt GR is combination of above.

Result:
alt: False, ctrl: True, altGr: False.

I have no idea why `alt` is not triggered in my case.

Comment: Can you check what the e.SystemKey is returning? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.keyeventargs.systemkey(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Return nothing. I found solution for my problem. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried this:

```
void MainWindow_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Key == Key.RightAlt)
    {
        // Do something
    } }
```

If not, please define what you have tried already.

Comment: I tried the most typical solutions like :
`e.Key == Key.RightAlt`
`e.KeyboardDevice.Modifiers.HasFlag(ModifierKeys.Alt)` etc
`Keyboard.IsKeyDown`